# find prime numbers between two numbers

Tags: java, numbers, find

I want to find prime numbers between two numbers that we get from the inputs, but I get this error:

> num cannot be resolved to a variable

I read the code many times but couldn't find the problem!
Can you help me?

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Start number: ");
        int number1 = input1.nextInt();
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter End number: ");
        int number2 = input2.nextInt();
        input1.close();
        input2.close();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int num=number1; num<number2; num++)
            if (number1<2 || number2<2 || number2<number1)
                break;
            else if (isPrime(num))
                counter++;
                System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println("Total Prime Numbers Between " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " => " + counter);
    }
    
    static boolean isPrime(int number) { 
        if (number<2)
            return false;
        for (int i=number; i<number; i++)
            if (number%i==0)
                return false;
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a very close look at this line which has a bug: `for (int i=number; i<number; i++)`

Comment: Is the problem only within the `isPrime()` method?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk error is in this line:                 
line 19, System.out.println(num);  (num is error) 
I don't understand! Thanks for help.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that's not the only bug. Look 3 lines below your call out.

Comment: @Bohemian VSCode just error in line 19 by "num"!

Comment: @MasoudKelaye what error? Edit your question to show the error. Remove all code not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem - keep removing code until you have the smallest amount that has the error. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then vote to reopen.

Comment: @Bohemian this is the error: num cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java ain't python: Indentation (or any from of whitespace) does not convey any code meaning.

The problem is the *scope* of `num` which is harder to see because your indentation is incorrect.

This code:

```java
for (int num=number1; num<number2; num++)
    if (number1<2 || number2<2 || number2<number1)
        break;
    else if (isPrime(num))
        counter++;
        System.out.println(num);
```

When properly formatted is:

```java
for (int num=number1; num<number2; num++)
    if (number1<2 || number2<2 || number2<number1)
        break;
    else if (isPrime(num))
        counter++;
System.out.println(num);
```

which shows the problem; the print is *outside* of the loop, so `num` is not defined there.

Use braces:

```java
for (int num=number1; num<number2; num++)
    if (number1<2 || number2<2 || number2<number1)
        break;
    else if (isPrime(num)) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

Or better yet, and it's best practice, is to use braces for all statement blocks, whether or not they are needed to compile:

```java
for (int num=number1; num<number2; num++) {
    if (number1<2 || number2<2 || number2<number1) {
        break;
    } else if (isPrime(num)) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```